# I have a Shopify website and there are google search console error : "Unparsable structured data issue detected for site."

Tags: shopify, google-search-console

Unparsable structured data issue detected for Shopify website.

"@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "Product",
    "@id": "https://example.com/products/full-clear-zirconia-silver-tennis-bracelet#product",
    "brand": {
        "@type": "Brand",
        "name": "belledesoiree.com"
    },
    "sku": "78969",
    "description": "
Timeless- Classy- Beautiful
If you buy this bracelet",

Answer (score 0):

The fix for me was to locate the file responsible for outputting the page, in my case it was  `article.liiquid` and `escape` the content only in the json portion.

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "Article",
  "articleBody": "{{ article.content | strip_html | escape }}", //<<
```